# Rotation and scale Changes appear to not save with Linked object

Tags: linked-data

I have a set of objects that I am importing into a main scene via linked connection. For some reason the changes I make to the rotation and sometimes the scale of these objects are not being saved. Particularly the root parent.

I have reloaded the objects back into the main scene many times after rechecking everything. I make sure to apply the rotations and scale throughout the hierarchy. For instance I am trying to align the object to the X axis.

In the object file the orientation is correct

[image]

In the main scene file the orientation is off
[image]

Comment: Hello, the arrow in the middle of the link icon besides the objects and collections names in the outliner means they are library overrides. Try right clicking in the outliner > Id Data > Delete Library Override or just in the transform channels > Remove overrides

Comment: It seems to have fixed itself after I restarted the computer.